# Como posso aplicar acréscimo e redução de percentual sobre valor unitário

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, firebird

O script abaixo calcula o valor de consumo referente a materiais e medicamentos , agrupando por paciente.

```
select
    coalesce( sum (
        (
        (L.QTDE) - coalesce(
            sum(
                (
                    select sum(QTDE)
                    from GECADDEV CD
                        inner join GELANDEV LD on CD.ID = LD.ID_GECADDEV
                    where L.ID_GELANSAI = LD.ID_GELANSAI
                        and LD.CONSOL = 'T'
                )
            ),
            0
        )
    ) *
        -- Nesse trecho que calculo acréscimo ou redução  
        (
            SELECT VALOR1
            FROM SPBRAVEN(5, L.ITEM, current_date, 1)
        ) * (1.10)),0)


from GECADSAI D
    inner join RECADATE A on D.PAC = A.REG
    inner join GELANSAI L on D.DOC = L.DOC
                            and D.ANO = L.ANO
                            and D.MES = L.MES
    inner join GEITENS I on L.ITEM = I.COD
    inner join RICADPAC CP on A.PRONT = CP.PRONT
where L.CONSOL = 'T'
    and D.CONV = e.conv
    and D.PAC = e.reg
    and char_length(D.PAC) > 6
    and A.PEXT = 'S'
    and i.classif in (2) --classificação do item sendo : 2 =  medicamento e 1 material
```

Porém, preciso aplicar uma regra que :
Caso o item seja classificado como material, eu aplique uma redução de -40% sobre o valor unitário.

E se for medicamento, aplique um acréscimo sobre de 10% sobre o valor

Alguém tem alguma ideia , tentei usar case e iff mas não consegui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando apenas o que está pedido na pergunta...

Faz um Case nesse trecho:

```
(
    SELECT VALOR1
    FROM SPBRAVEN(5, L.ITEM, current_date, 1)
) * (1.10)),0)
```

Ficando:

```
(
    SELECT VALOR1
    FROM SPBRAVEN(5, L.ITEM, current_date, 1)
) * (Case when i.classif = 2 then (1.10) when i.classif = 1 then (0.60) else (1) end)),0)
```

Porém, você poderia parametrizar esse fator pela classificação do item, assim não precisaria alterar a query futuramente quando houver alteração nessa taxa.

Comment: Obrigado @Rovann , sua solução atendeu perfeitamente ao que precisava.
Esse fator já é parametrizado via aplicação, porém são muitas tabelas que envolvem tal gerenciamento. Como o Percentual não sofre reajuste , e ser apenas um relatório para um usuário final optei tratar no sql mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Outra alternativa seria utilizar o [IIF](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-iif.html) que nada mais é, do que um if ternário, você poderia colocar algo como:

```
(
    SELECT VALOR1
    FROM SPBRAVEN(5, L.ITEM, current_date, 1)
) * IIF(i.classif = 2, 1.10, 0.60)
```

ou seja, se a classificação for = 2, multiplica por 1.10, se não, 0.60, ai é só adaptar a sua necessidade, espero ter ajudado.